# How to pass a python object from a robot framework test case to a keyword?

Tags: python, object, variables, arguments, robotframework

I'm kind of new in Python and robot framework. So I might miss something obvious. I have experience in .NET programming and used to work with entities/object, which we used for database filling and api responses. I'm trying to do the same with the tests in robot framework, but run into the following problem.

I'm trying to pass an object from a robot framework test case to a keyword, though it says "[FAIL INSIDE] Resolving variable '${person.Id}' failed: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Id'"

My code in the person.py file:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class person(object):
    #ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Id='myId'
        self.Name='Jack' 

    def set_id(self, Id):
        self.Id=Id

    def set_name(self, Name):
        self.Name=Name
        return self
    
    def get_a_person(self):
        return self
```

My code in the .resource file:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        
Library         person.py

*** Keywords ***
Get Person Entity
    ${person}     Get A Person
    RETURN     ${person}

Insert person in database     
    [Arguments]     ${person}    
    Execute Sql String    INSERT INTO [Database].[dbo].[Person] (Id,Name) VALUES ('${person.Id}', '${person.Name}');
```

My code in the .robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        
Library         person.py

*** Test Cases ***
1. My Example Test
    ${testPerson}    Get Person Entity
    ${testPerson}    Set Name    Adam
    Run Keywords    Insert person in database     person=${testPerson}
```

So it doesn't work when trying to insert the person in the database. When I change the Insert person in database to logging and try to log the testperson's his name, it is working. During debugging I see that the object in the test case is still a person object. Though when it has been passed to the resource file, the object is suddenly a string.

Comment: Could you try to remove `Run keywords` from the test case last line and check gain? E.g. line    ```Run Keywords    Insert person in database     person=${testPerson}```   should be     ```Insert person in database     person=${testPerson}```. 
`

Comment: Just did, but it didn't help unfortunately. The same error message pops up.

Comment: You see,  your way to pass the object is correct. I even executed your example on my side and it works Ok. I've just removed 'run keywords' and fixed the Resource setting.  So, my first guess is that there is syntax error left somewhere, but due to StackO code formatting it is hidden. Could I ask you to examine your own example here, whether it s the same character-to-character to your real code?

Comment: For example, extra space character here `person= ${testPerson}` leads to converting object to string! Note space char after equal sign.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to make it working, knowing that this code was correct. There were no extra spacing, but perhaps some hidden character or something? I couldn't find the cause, but when I made a new keyword for inserting person in database, it did work.